# Filter HTML table with function using angular.forEach to replace many if/else statements

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-filter

Have an HTML table in angularJS app:

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="player in playerdata | filter:tableFilter" >
```

Have a function called `tableFilter`, which looks like so:

```
function tableFilter (player) {
    if ( player.GP      <   $scope.GPMin    ||  player.GP   >   $scope.GPMax)   { return false; };
    if ( player.GA60    <   $scope.GA60Min  ||  player.GA60 >   $scope.GA60Max) { return false; };
    if ( player.SA60    <   $scope.SA60Min  ||  player.SA60 >   $scope.SA60Max) { return false; };
    if ( player.FA60    <   $scope.FA60Min  ||  player.FA60 >   $scope.FA60Max) { return false; };
    if ( player.CA60    <   $scope.CA60Min  ||  player.CA60 >   $scope.CA60Max) { return false; };
    return true;
};
```

Which works fine: it removes the players from the table as desired when conditions are not met.

However, likely see the pattern emerging here, and since I have many more than 5 `stats`, I need to tidy this up for reuse. My failed attempt:

```
function tableFilter (player) {
    var stats = [
        'GP','GA60','SA60','FA60','CA60' // etc
    ];
    angular.forEach(stats, function (stat) {
        var statMin = $scope[stat + 'Min'];
        var statMax = $scope[stat + 'Max'];
        var p = player[stat];

        if ( p < statMin || p > statMax ) { return false; };
    });

    return true;
};
```

This will run and I can `console.log` the results as expected, but the HTML does not update (or re-render with the filtered values only).

What am I missing here, how can I get the table to filter with the second function?

Comment: According to your example, it seems you're missing the corresponding <td>'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a way to break out of that loop. `return false` in the scope of `forEach` will not return from the `filter` function - so you're returning `true` every time once you `return false` inside `forEach` (this call is just breaking from the loop). You can set your desired return boolean in a variable, and break from that loop when found - then returning the `var`. Observe the (untested) following...

```
function tableFilter (player) {
    var stats = [
        'GP','GA60','SA60','FA60','CA60' // etc
    ];

    var truthy = true;

    angular.forEach(stats, function (stat) {
        var statMin = $scope[stat + 'Min'];
        var statMax = $scope[stat + 'Max'];
        var p = player[stat];

        if(p < statMin || p > statMax) {
            truthy = false;  // -- store value to return from .filter
            return;          // -- return from forEach block
        }
    });

    return truthy;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `return false;` statement is in the forEach function, not the filter function. Have it assign to a variable local to the filter function, and then return the final result.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the shape of your data, e.g.

```
var filter = function(player) {
    //player = { GA: 12, GP: 15, ... }
    $scope.stats = { GA: { min: 10, max: 20 }, GP: { ... } ... }
    var show = true;
    angular.forEach($scope.stats, function(item, argname) {
        if(player[argname] < item.min || player[argname] > item.max) {
            show = false;
        }
    });
    return show;
}
```

Note that angular.forEach will enumerate through the object's properties.